# Why is String -> &str different in the impl for Deref and AsRef?

Tags: string, rust

Why does `ops::Deref` take a `String` to a `&str` differently then `AsRef`?

This is the [impl in `ops::Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2408)

```
impl ops::Deref for String {
    type Target = str;

    #[inline]
    fn deref(&self) -> &str {
        unsafe { str::from_utf8_unchecked(&self.vec) }
    }
}
```

That's different from [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2575),

```rust
impl AsRef<str> for String {
    #[inline]
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &str {
        self
    }
}
```

What is the difference here between `.as_ref()` and `.deref()`

Comment: `as_ref()` relies on `deref()` to do the actual work of "creating" the slice given the underlying `Vec<u8>`. That's why `AsRef::as_ref()` can just return `self`, a `&String`, where `&str` is expected.

Comment: https://dev.to/zhanghandong/rust-concept-clarification-deref-vs-asref-vs-borrow-vs-cow-13g6

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html => "Deref should only be implemented for smart pointers"

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `&String` where `&str` is asked due to a type coercion rule:

```
&T or &mut T to &U if T implements Deref<Target = U>
```

> `T` is `String` and `U` is `str` in this case.
>
> ```rust
> impl ops::Deref for String {
>    type Target = str;
>
>    #[inline]
>    fn deref(&self) -> &str {
>        unsafe { str::from_utf8_unchecked(&self.vec) }
>    }
> }
> ```

And as you can see, this rule relies on the trait `Deref`. And This is what @user4815162342 says `as_ref() relies on deref() to do the actual work` means.

For more info about type coercion, see [Coercions Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types).

Answer (score 0):

The type of `self` in the method, `AsRef::as_ref`, is `&String`, per the definition of the `AsRef` trait.

```
pub trait AsRef<T>where
    T: ?Sized,{
    // Required method
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &T;
}
```

As such, when this `&String` is being returned/assigned into a variable expecting `&str`, `String`'s implementation of `Deref::deref` is noticed and used by the compiler to automatically convert/interpret/view the `&String` as `&str`. Recall, the definition of `Deref`:

```
pub trait Deref {
    type Target: ?Sized;

    // Required method
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target;
}
```

Rust does not perform silent conversion but this is an exception to that rule.